# rails 3 best practice for handling attribute with fixed possibilities

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database-design, ruby-on-rails-3.2, bit-manipulation

For example if I have an attribute that is limited to a short list of values like:

```
ways = {:way_1 => 1, :way_2 => 2, :way_3 => 3}
```

What is the best practice for handling this attribute, for both cases:

- User can choose only one value (radio button)
- User can choose multiple values (checkbox)

For the first case I would use hash defined in an initializer and save the integer value, for second case I thought of bit manipulation to represent all possible combinations.

Is there a best practice for handling both cases in rails 3?

Edit:
I found this gem [BitmaskAttributes](https://github.com/joelmoss/bitmask_attributes) which handles the bit manipulation nicely, but I still want to know if this is the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array and serialize this array in a **text attribute** in your model

```
class Expense < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :ways
  # other model code
end
```

then when saving your model, you can do it like this

```
Expense.new(:ways => [1, 2])
```